# Strange behavior from monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand Monads and I did a practice question:
For the problem I do two things take in a function and an Integer, than I process it in the following manner:
I take the value the int supplied and than split the integer like so:

```
3 -> (2,1) (1,2)
4 -> (3,1) (2,2) (1,3)

so on.
```

Which works and is implemented as follows:

```
numberSplit :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
numberSplit 0 = []
numberSplit 1 = []
numberSplit n = numberSplitHelper 1 (n - 1)

--Helper functions --

numberSplitHelper :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int)]
numberSplitHelper 0 0 = []
numberSplitHelper 0 1 = []
numberSplitHelper 1 0 = []
numberSplitHelper 1 1 = [(1, 1)]
numberSplitHelper n 1 = [(n, 1)]
numberSplitHelper n m = (n, m) : numberSplitHelper (n + 1) (m - 1)
```

Afterwords I will apply the function recursively to every value in the list returned from the numberSplit function and I am trying to do it with monads as a practice for monads.
So for example if I input in:

```
(sort
            (andExpressionsAtSize 
                (\ i -> if i == 1 then 
                        [EBase True,EBase False] 
                    else if i == 2 then 
                        [ENot (EBase True),ENot (EBase False)] 
                    else []) 
                3))
```

My expected output is:

```
[EAnd (EBase False,EBase False)
        ,EAnd (EBase False,EBase True)
        ,EAnd (EBase True,EBase False)
        ,EAnd (EBase True, EBase True)]
```

I attempted to do the following:

```
andExpressionsAtSize :: (Int -> [Expression]) -> Int -> [Expression]
andExpressionsAtSize f 0 = []
andExpressionsAtSize f n = do
    intList <- numberSplit n
    intList >>= f
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘(,) Int’ with ‘[]’
  Expected: [Expression]
    Actual: (Int, Expression)
```

Based on my understanding of the List Monad it does the following:

```
1. It takes in a list.
2. Applies the function on the left hand side to the list recursively.
```

So it would apply f to the head all the way to the tail. So based on that understanding

```
intList >>= f
```

Should return a type of [Expression] which it does not, this confuses me, can someone clarify what is happening?

Edit:
Some people pointed out that I never used EAnd, I forgot to mention that in the output every element should be joined by an EAnd.

Comment: How do you expect your function to return an output including `EAnd`s, when its input doesn't include any, and it never creates any itself?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica oops I forgot to add that every element should be joined by an EAnd

Comment: `intList` has type `(Int, Int)`, not `[Int]`. I'm not sure how you want to use that pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intList` is not a list, as its name might suggest! In the snippet

```
do
    {- ... -}
    x <- y
    {- here -}
```

if `y` is a list, then `x` will be one of the *elements* of the list in the continuation marked `here`. You write:

```
do
    intList <- numberSplit n
    {- ... -}
```

Since `numberSplit n` is a list, `intList` will be a member of that list -- that is, a pair of type `(Int, Int)`.

(I believe this is your core confusion, and once corrected you will have some ideas about things to try to fix the remainder of your code; but if this belief is incorrect say a bit about where I've gone wrong and I'll try to help further.)